# Doctrine turns given value into null

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem that looks kinda hard to describe, but i'm gonna try anyway.

In my MatchesResultscontroller, i've got the following code, to build up an entity:

```
$em             = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');    
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        // get id of current match
        $match_id       = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('match', 1);

        // find match based on current match id
        $results        = $em->getRepository('Competitions\Entity\MatchesResults')->findBy(
        ['match_id' => $match_id]
        );

        $matchresults = new \Competitions\Entity\MatchesResults();

        // Input
        $matchresults->stek             = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Stek');
        $matchresults->member_id        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Name');
        $matchresults->weight           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Gewicht');
        $matchresults->points           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Punten');
        $matchresults->match_id         = $match_id;
        $matchresults->amount           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Aantal');

        // Add
        $em->persist($matchresults);
        $em->flush($matchresults);

        // Redirect back to the competition overview
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin-match');
```

The file MatchesResults.php looks like this

```
 <?php
namespace Competitions\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**  
@ORM\Table()
@ORM\Entity
@ORM\Table(name="matches_results") 
*/

class MatchesResults {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
public $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $match_id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $member_id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $stek;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $weight; 

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $amount;

/** @ORM\Column(type="float") */
public $points;

/** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
public $position;

public $var;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Competitions\Entity\Matches", mappedBy="Members")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="match_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
public $result;

public function getResult() {
    return $this->result;
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Members\Entity\Members")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="member_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")   <----- problem here
 */
public $member;

public function getMember() { 
    return $this->member; 
}
}
```

When i need to get an overview of all results of a given match, with the correct user linked to that result, it works perfectly.
However, when i need to add a new result, I get a member_id = null, since doctrine is trying to get the member_id of a non existing result.

```
            $matchresults->stek             = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Stek');
        $matchresults->member_id        = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Name');
        $matchresults->weight           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Gewicht');
        $matchresults->points           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Punten');
        $matchresults->match_id         = $match_id;
        $matchresults->amount           = $this->getRequest()->getPost('Res_Aantal');
```

This code does set all values correctly into the entity, but the entities member_id field is just overwritten.
How would i solve this issue?
I could make a separate file that does not contain the troubling line, but i don't think that is a very elegant solution.

Mark

Comment: You shouldn't be using foreign key references within your entities. The whole point of `Doctrine` is to allow you to use the actual object instances (so `int $member_id` becomes `Member $member`). Is there any special reason as to why you using it this way?

Comment: Well, to be painfully honest with you, it's because i didn't create what i have to work with right now, i merely have to improve on it. Now, as to your answer ( The whole point of Doctrine is to allow you to use the actual object instances (so int $member_id becomes Member $member). ), how does that change the outcome?

Comment: It doesn't change the outcome as much as it changes the people who write it.